# How to get all the elements array dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

i have in my `$string` an **object array** and i want to get all the elements array dynamically for each line knowing that i don't know how elements i'll get in that string, now i have **4 entrees**, and maybe after i'll get just 2 or 10, and how to retrieve that data for each key.

My try:

```
var_dump($string) = 

array(4) {
  ["_1514316350293_293"] => array(4) {
    ["customer_group"] => string(1) "3"
    ["condition"] => string(1) "2"
    ["somme"] => string(6) "500.00"
    ["price"] => string(4) "0.00"
  }
  ["_1514316394524_524"] => array(4) {
    ["customer_group"] => string(1) "2"
    ["condition"] => string(1) "2"
    ["somme"] => string(6) "500.00"
    ["price"] => string(4) "0.00"
  }
  ["_1514316395828_828"] => array(4) {
    ["customer_group"] => string(1) "3"
    ["condition"] => string(1) "1"
    ["somme"] => string(6) "500.00"
    ["price"] => string(5) "29.40"
  }
  ["_1514316396756_756"] => array(4) {
    ["customer_group"] => string(1) "2"
    ["condition"] => string(1) "1"
    ["somme"] => string(6) "500.00"
    ["price"] => string(5) "29.40"
  }
}

foreach($string as $key=>$value){
    var_dump($value);
}

result=
  array(4) {
  ["customer_group"] => string(1) "3"
  ["condition"] => string(1) "2"
  ["somme"] => string(6) "500.00"
  ["price"] => string(4) "0.00"
}

array(4) {
  ["customer_group"] => string(1) "2"
  ["condition"] => string(1) "2"
  ["somme"] => string(6) "500.00"
  ["price"] => string(4) "0.00"
}

array(4) {
  ["customer_group"] => string(1) "3"
  ["condition"] => string(1) "1"
  ["somme"] => string(6) "500.00"
  ["price"] => string(5) "29.40"
}

array(4) {
  ["customer_group"] => string(1) "2"
  ["condition"] => string(1) "1"
  ["somme"] => string(6) "500.00"
  ["price"] => string(5) "29.40"
}
```

I miss the little finition to have what i need

Comment: so what you want now? What is expected?

Comment: Now i want to get the `customer_group`, `condition`, `somme`, `price` for each array so how to select the first array, the 2nd etc but dynamically, i mean now like you see in my `$string` i have 4 arrays, maybe after i'll get 2 array or 8 or... for exemple

Comment: you want to get only these fields customer_group, condition, somme, price , right?

Comment: @Pr_co  check my answer once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if ***you don't know about sub-array length and either it is associative or numeric***, then also you can get all values like below:-

```
foreach($string as $key=>$value){
    $keys = array_keys($value);
    foreach($keys as $key){
      echo $value[$key].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/925895

***Or:-***

```
foreach($string as $key=>$value){
    $values = array_values($value);
    foreach($values as $value){
      echo $value.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/925897

***To check condition do like below:-***

```
foreach($string as $key=>$value){
  $keys = array_keys($value);
  if (in_array('customer_group',$keys) && $value['customer_group'] == 3 && in_array('condition',$keys) && $value['condition'] == 2 && in_array('somme',$keys) && $value['somme'] == 500.00 && in_array('price',$keys) && $value['price'] == 0.00){
    echo "oh yes";
  }
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/925925

**Reference:-**

[PHP: array_keys - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

[PHP: array_values - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but now how i select the values of the  array 1, array2 etc. What i want to do is some condition with this values something like : `if ($customer_group == 3 && $condition == 2 && $somme == 500.00 && $price == 0.00){some logic}` i do this for each array i don't know how to select them form the different arrays

Comment: Thanks @Alive to Die--Anant singh for your time

Comment: @Pr_co  glad to hel you :):)

Comment: @Pr_co  what? din't get you. Please ask a new question with good input +code-effort+ expected-outcome. Address me the link too, if i have time i will give you solution. Otherwise some-one for-sure answer you. Asking new question in comment is not a good idea at all.

Comment: Sorry, i Forget the 2secong part of the comment: here is: Singh ? have you an idea how to replace all the conditions values like this: `if ($value['condition'] == 2){ ($value['condition'] == 2) == >}` `"0" = ">", "1"= ">=", "2"= "<", "3"="<=", "4"="=="

Comment: @Pr_co  please ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

You can try [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function

```
var_dump( array_values( $string ) );
```

It will print all the values in the array

---

If you want to get particular record

```
$rows = array_values( $string );
var_dump( $rows[2] );
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer but i want to get the keys and values for each array and not just all the values

Comment: As my question says, i want to get the records dynamically without put the 1 or 2 or ... because  the records are not fixed to 4 but +1

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 $string = [["customer_group" => "3", "condition" => "2", "somme" => "500.00", "price" => "0.00"]];

    print_r($string);
    $newArr = array_map(function ($v) {
        return [
            'customer_group' => $v['customer_group'], 
            'condition' => $v['condition'], 
            'somme' => $v['somme'], 
            'price' => $v['price']
       ];
    }, $string);
    print_r($newArr);
```